# Rails link_to Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I'm trying to construct a Link. The resulting Link should look something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/re_goal/edit/2
```

This is what I came up with:

```
<%= @issue.re_artifact_properties.collect { |properties| link_to properties.name, re_goal_path()}.to_sentence %>
```

It now says that i may have ambiguous routes.

```
content_url has the following required parameters: ["projects", :project_id, "re_goal", :id]
```

But if i pass the project_id as an option, the constructed link looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/1/re_goal/1
```

Does any1 has an idea on how to construct the correct link?

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got a nested route being generated there. Either supply the required params, or remove the nested route.

Or go for the 'middle way' of shallow routes:

```
resources :projects, :shallow => true do 
  resources :re_goal
end
```

Comment: thanks. this wasnt exactly the solution but your hint was enough for me to find it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a route that takes parameters, you must supply them. `rake routes` can be useful for determining what arguments are required and what order they should be provided in. Your route probably looks like this:

```
projects/:project_id/re_goal/:id
```

In this case you will need to provide `project_id` and `id` as the two arguments to `re_goal_path`. If you omit them you get the "required parameters" error. It's not clear from your question how you get a project or a goal from your `@issue`, but that's what you need.

Comment: my goals look like this: http://pastie.org/private/sokt19xecb4sseujqb1hca   the problem is that he seems to require arguments he shouldnt need. i just want goal/1/edit not projects/1/goal/1/edit, nevertheless he wants me to pass the project id.  the problem is not getting the required project id, this is saved directly in the issues object